# Parse SQL variables with session array in PHP

Tags: php, arrays

trying to parse multiple sql variables from one file to another using session arrays but i cant. Whats the part iam missing here?

Thanks in advance.

file1.php

```
session_start();
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result,MYSQL_BOTH)) {
    echo "<tr>";
    $id=$row['id'];
    $array[] = $id;
}
$_SESSION['id'] = $array;
```

file2.php

```
session_start();
foreach( $array as $id ) {
    echo $id;
}
```

Comment: Why `MYSQL_BOTH` as you are only using the assoc part use `MYSQL_ASSOC` instead

Comment: `$id=$row['id']; $array[] = $id;` can be simplified to `$array[] = $row['id'];`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because `$array` isn't your shared variable. `$_SESSION['id']` is what you need to be reading from.

Example (taken from: https://web.archive.org/web/20080707052007/http://www.phpriot.com/articles/intro-php-sessions/7):

Page1.php

```
<?php
// begin the session
session_start();

// create an array
$my_array=array('cat', 'dog', 'mouse', 'bird', 'crocodile', 'wombat', 'koala', 'kangaroo');

// put the array in a session variable
$_SESSION['animals']=$my_array;

// a little message to say we have done it
echo 'Putting array into a session variable';
?>
```

Page2.php

```
<?php
// begin the session
session_start();

// loop through the session array with foreach
foreach($_SESSION['animals'] as $key=>$value)
    {
    // and print out the values
    echo 'The value of $_SESSION['."'".$key."'".'] is '."'".$value."'".' <br />';
    }
?>
```

As mentioned in the comments, the `echo` on page2.php is OTT. A simpler method would be:
`echo "Value of {$_SESSION[$key]} is $value<br />" ;` (credit: RiggsFolly)

Comment: `echo "The value of {$_SESSION[$key]} is $value<br />";` is a bit easier to chew on

Comment: @RiggsFolly indeed. I took the example straight from the URL, so I didn't want to change any as it would be bad for the reference. I'll update my post.

Answer (score 1):

In your code example you're not reading `$array` from `$_SESSION`.

Also keep in mind that `$_SESSION` stores everything as strings unless you implement your own [session handler](http://php.net/manual/en/class.sessionhandler.php).

Comment: So how would i do that? can you help me?

Comment: On `file2.php` do `var_dump($_SESSION);` to see what's in it. Work from there.